# Is there any method to provide a drop down without using the <button> syntax?

Tags: html, css

I have a blogging site & want to make a drop down menu but not with the  syntax. I have already created the menu hyperlinks on menu bar & I want to include the drop down in that hyperlinks only because I have used the CSS to design it in my way & don't want to spoil that design. Please suggest me what to do.

Adding a  syntax spoils the whole look & forms a box like design.

Comment: You need to include HTML/CSS/JavaScript that you currently have and make your question clearer.  At this point no one can help.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item" data-url="#page1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item" data-url="#page2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item" data-url="#page3">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <span id="menu-button" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dropdown>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown>ul>li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.3em 1em 0.3em 1em;
  margin: 0;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.dropdown>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown>span {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1em;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.dropdown>span:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-button").click(function() {
    toggleMenu();
  });

    $(".menu-item").click(function(){
        var url=$(this).attr("data-url");
        console.log(url);
        toggleMenu();
    });
});

function toggleMenu() {
  var slider = "#menu";
  var sliderHeight = $(slider).height();
  if ($(slider).css("margin-top") == -sliderHeight + "px" && !$(slider).is(':animated')) {
    $(slider).animate({
      "margin-top": '+=' + sliderHeight
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
  } else {
    if (!$(slider).is(':animated')) {
      $(slider).animate({
        "margin-top": '-=' + sliderHeight
      });
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with WordPress. Where did you get that from? Yes, the OP's question was vague, but he asked for a dropdown menu, so I delivered.